# Tableau column ABC not showing

Tags: tableau-api

Could someone help me figure this out? For some reason my Tableau is not showing the ABC column next to a Row. I'm trying to do a sum for all orders by product category and for some reason because I'm missing the ABC column, it's not letting do it.

Thank you for your help![enter image description here][1]

Comment: Your screenshot is missing, try uploading again please.

Comment: It won't let me add it because I don't have enough reputation points

Comment: After adding`product category` to rows, please double click the measure field which you trying to sum.

Comment: It's still not doing it. I wish I could show you a picture.. Basically those fields are getting added (Product category to rows and the measure field under Marks (sun of measure field) however I can't see any of the balances from the measure field next to the product category

Comment: Try editing your question now, please

Comment: By the way which version of Tableau are you using? 2020.1?